# Pandas apply conditional statement : compare x to the mean of the rolling window

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

Trying to use pandas apply function to compare each value of A against its mean for the window.

Current code implementation :

```
m = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['A'] > x.shift(3)['MEAN OF WINDOW'] else 0, axis = 1)
```

Not sure if this really works, as it takes forever to execute. I must be doing something wrong

[image: current data frame]

Actual dataframe view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `bfill`

```
(df['A'] > df['MEAN OF WINDOW'].bfill()).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question. can u check again please

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz would you like show us the data not pic ?

Comment: Check now. i uploaded the dataframe view

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz also I do not think in your case you need the apply, since bfill with simple compare are good for this type of case /

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz please check the output of `(df['A'] > df['MEAN_A'].bfill()).astype(int)`